# 4th order Runge-Kutta for infinite square well

Tags: python, python-3.x, runge-kutta, quantum-computing

The following code works for n = 1 but for higher energy levels the wave function is flipped in the x-axis compared to the expected wave function. Does anyone know why this is? V(x) is set to be 0 for all x and the energies were all correct compared to expected values. All constants have been defined.

```
x = np.arange(-a,a,h)

def f(r,x,E):
psi = r[0]
phi = r[1]
fpsi = phi
fphi = (2*m/(hbar**2))*(V(x)-E)*psi

return np.array([fpsi,fphi],float) 


def RungeKutta2d(xpoints,E):
r = [0,1]
psipoints = []
phipoints = [] 
for x in xpoints:
    psipoints.append(r[0])
    phipoints.append(r[1])
    k1 = h*f(r,x,E) 
    k2 = h*f(r+0.5*k1, x+0.5*h,E)
    k3 = h*f(r+0.5*k2, x+0.5*h,E)
    k4 = h*f(r+k3, x+h,E)
    r = r + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6

psipoints.append(r[0])
phipoints.append(r[1])
return np.array(psipoints)


def Secant(E1,E2):
psi1 = RungeKutta2d(xpoints,E1)[N]
psi2 = RungeKutta2d(xpoints,E2)[N]

tolerance = e/1000             
while abs(E2-E1) > tolerance: 
    E3 = E2 - psi2*(E2-E1)/(psi2-psi1)  
    E1 = E2 
    E2 = E3 
    psi1 = RungeKutta2d(xpoints,E1)[N]
    psi2 = RungeKutta2d(xpoints,E2)[N]

return E3
```

Comment: Why do you think this solution is wrong? What do compare it to? Is there a link or otherwise an reference? Note that the boundary value problem is homogeneous, so you can scale it with any non-zero factor and still get a solution. // What is the relation between `N` and `a` and `h`? Are you certain that `x[N]=a`? Would it not be better to go the way `x,h = np.linspace(-a,a,N+1, returnstep=True)`?

Comment: Also, please extend this to a minimal working example. It is, for example, unclear what the `n` of the intro text does in the code. You might want to use `scipy.integrate.odeint` and `scipy.optimize.findroot` to make the code more compact by replacing the homebrewed routines. Note that, as there appear to be no direct errors in the code, this is or may become off-topic here, and be better suited for physics.SE or scicomp.SE.